# userRole always returns "user" even when admin

Tags: typescript, botframework, microsoft-teams

i'm using the getTeamMembers() method to see which members are admins in a private team, except even when logged in as an admin, the userRole value is "user". Anyone can help?

```
import { BotDeclaration, } from "express-msteams-host";
import {
  ActionTypes,
  CardFactory, MemoryStorage, MessageFactory,
  TeamsActivityHandler, TaskModuleTaskInfo,
  TurnContext, TaskModuleRequest, TaskModuleResponse, TeamsInfo
} from "botbuilder";
import * as Util from "util";

const TextEncoder = Util.TextEncoder;

@BotDeclaration(
  "/api/messages",
  new MemoryStorage(),
  process.env.MICROSOFT_APP_ID,
  process.env.MICROSOFT_APP_PASSWORD)
export class LearningTeamsBot extends TeamsActivityHandler {
  constructor() {
    super();

    // create handlers
    this.onMessage(async (context, next) => {
      console.log(await TeamsInfo.getTeamMembers(context))
```

Answer (score 0):

We could able to reproduce the issue on our side. Raised a bug for this. We don't have ETA to share when it will be fixed.

Comment: Currently this is by design.